# Classification of unevenly sampled data using KNN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I have a dataset where I have `360 samples` for `class 0` and only `44 samples` for `class 1`. When I fit a `KNN model` to the data using `k=3` the model misclassifies lots of samples as `class 0`. What is the best way to deal with such unevenly sampled data? I could set `k=1` but from what I have read leads to a noise having a strong effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341/knn-and-unbalanced-classes) on CrossValidated, especially the third answer. One approach mentioned, for example, is to weigh neighbors "by the inverse of their class size". In your example with `k=3`, this would mean that in a situation where two nearest neighbors are `class 0`, and one nearest neighbor is `class 1`, the label would be `class 1` since 1/44 > 2/360. This is only one approach and you can check out more approaches in the discussion linked above. I hope this helps!